# When to change current_clocksource

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, clock-synchronization

I am running an Ubuntu 16.04 machine on a M4.xlarge in AWS EC2. I was reading about some of the performance tuning that Netflix did for their EC2 machines (link: http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2015-03-03/performance-tuning-linux-instances-on-ec2.html).

One thing the recommend is changing the clock source:

> echo tsc > /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/current_clocksource

I'm not sure if this is useful for 16.04. Is there a good explanation of when to use xen (which is the default) and when to use tsc?

Comment: Nothing is crashing. And there is no mention of tsc. From the Netflix post, it seems like they made the change from a performance standpoint - not because there was something crashing

Comment: Might help to first understand what it is and what it does.  https://xenbits.xen.org/docs/4.3-testing/misc/tscmode.txt & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter